# Android game fixed timestep gitter

Tags: java, android, game-loop

After reading about implementing a fixed timestep as set out here:

http://gafferongames.com/game-physics/fix-your-timestep/

I've implemented my own version of the algorithm in Java on Android, which has given me a great improvement, but I can't seem to eradicate an occasional gitter.

My GameTimer class contains a method called tick() which is called every frame to advance time, along with canStep() and step() methods as below:

```
public void tick() {
    long thisTime = System.nanoTime();
    frameTime = thisTime - lastTime;
    frameTimeMs = (int)(frameTime / NANO_TO_MILLI);
    frameCounter++;
    secondCounter -= frameTime;
    if(secondCounter <= 0) {
        fps = frameCounter;
        frameCounter = 0;
        secondCounter += NANO_TO_SECOND;
    }
    lastTime = thisTime;

    accumulator += Math.min(frameTimeMs, deltaTime * 5);//frameskip >5 frames
    alpha = accumulator / deltaTime;
}

public boolean canStep() {
    return accumulator >= deltaTime;
}

public void step() {
    accumulator -= deltaTime;
    alpha = accumulator / deltaTime;
}
```

NB: deltaTime holds 1000f divided by the desired number of updates per second (e.g. 30).

My main game loop runs this logic per frame as follows:

```
gameTimer.tick();
while(gameTimer.canStep()) {
    update();
    gameTimer.step();
}

draw();
```

To calculate a game object's movement I do the following:

```
float time = gameTimer.getDeltaTime() / 1000f; //how much of a second per update
velocity = speed * direction * time; //simplified: velocity, speed & direction are vec3s
previousPosition = position;//simplified: values are copied
position += velocity;
```

A moving game object's draw position is then calculated at draw time using linear interpolation:

```
lerp(drawPosition, previousPosition, position, 1.0f + gameTimer.getAlpha());
```

The game draws at between 50 to 60 fps. Experimenting with the updates per second hasn't yielded any better results. Also, increasing or decreasing the frameskip doesn't remove the gitter either. The object suddenly jumps forward a few pixels every now and again and I'm struggling to iron the issue out.

Can anyone see any obvious problems with the above code that I'm missing?

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: The problem is with the time source and the way graphic buffers are queued.  See https://source.android.com/devices/graphics/architecture.html#loops for an explanation of the problem and how to use Choreographer to fix it.